# ServiceNotFoundException: HWIOAuthBundle + Salesforce resource owner

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle, symfony-2.6

I am trying to get [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) the bundle installed & configured but I am having some issues. This is what I have done:

1) Enable the bundle at `AppKernel.php`:

```
new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
```

2) Add this line to the `config.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: sonata.yml }
    - { resource: hwi.yml }
```

3) Write the following at `hwi.yml` file:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: admin_area

    resource_owners:
        salesforce:
            type:             salesforce
            client_id:        <cliend_id> 
            client_secret:    <client_secret>
```

4) Add the routes at the very beginning at `routing.yml`:

```
#FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

#HWIOAuthBundle
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login

#SonataAdmin
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

When I call at browser: `http://applocal.dev/app_dev.php` I got this error:

> ServiceNotFoundException in
>   CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58: The service
>   "hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" has a dependency on a non-existent
>   service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.admin_area".

What I am missing here? Why is that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you didn't configured oauth firwall

Pls check that you have at app/config/security.yml something like:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        admin_area:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                    google:             "/login/check-google"
                    my_custom_provider: "/login/check-custom"
                    my_github:          "/login/check-github"
                login_path:        /login
                use_forward:       false
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```